# Html5: how to move a div inside another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to move a div inside another object.
I have the following html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="uno" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:9999">
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br />
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br />
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br />
    </div>
    <div id="due" style="position:relative;z-index:0">
        <embed src="test.pdf" style="width:500px;height:500px"/>
    </div>

    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Clicca" />
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#uno").animate({ marginLeft: "+=20px", marginTop:"+=100px"},1000);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

The "uno" div is always below the "due"...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you position the `<div id="uno">` absolutely?

Comment: I guess you mean that the pdf always shows on top of the lorem ipsum text. If so, then it might be related to some problem with the embed tag but I can't guess more than that without a live example.

Comment: The above example works in Firefox, and Chrome, but not in Safari and IE.

Answer (score 1):

What if you use an iframe instead of an embed like this, then the text goes over the pdf.

```
    <div id="uno" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1; background: #f00;"> 
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br /> 
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br /> 
        Lorem ipsum bla bla bla<br /> 
    </div> 

   <div id="due" style="position:relative;z-index:0; overflow: hidden;"> 
         <iframe src="test.pdf" width="500" height="500"></iframe> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written your code the `due` div will always be below the `uno` div.

If you want the `due` div inside the `uno` div then you need to put it inside the `uno` div:

```
<div id="uno">
   <div id="due">
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want them to appear side by side then you need to use some css tag's. [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) has guides to this